# Django Admin: JSONField default empty dict wont save in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-jsonfield

in my model defn i have

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
.....
.......
.........

media_data=JSONField(default=dict)
```

I created a default admin

When i attempt to save without touching the field, i get a `this field is required` error.

[image: field is required]

It looks like a form validation issue because I can programatically save the model instance from code without issue.

Why is this happening?
have i missed something silly?

Comment: No, it's indeed a validation problem. For mysterious reasons, {} is not considered "valid json". You have to add `blank=True`.

Comment: much grr. thank you for the confirmation. is there docs somewhere about this?

Comment: You might want to document it yourself in Django's [ticket system](https://code.djangoproject.com/) :).

Comment: The docs , the meaning of blank=True in terms of validation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#blank

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. What happening.
   when dive into the source code. we can see the following call stack:

```
    1) form.is_valid() 
       ->form.full_clean()
        -->form._clean_fields()
         ---> self.cleand_data[name] = field.clean(value)
    2) field.clean(value)
        -> self.to_python(value)
        -> self.validate(value)
```

when look into the source code ,you can find that,it's mainly because the `empty_values` check.

```
# These values, if given to validate(), will trigger the self.required check.
EMPTY_VALUES = (None, '', [], (), {})
```

as you can see the empty dict `{}` is as an empty value for JSONField. so it will raise Error.

2. What can we do?
   the Solution would be to customize the models.JSONField and forms.JSONField like below.

forms.py

```py
from django.contrib.postgres import forms

class MyJSONField(forms.JSONField):
    empty_values = [None, "", [], ()]
```

db/fields.py

```py
class MyJSONField(JSONField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        from ..forms import MyJSONField

        return super().formfield(**{"form_class": MyJSONField, **kwargs})
```

Comment: great investigation! thanks. If you are interested, you may want to consider submiting a PR to the Django codebase for this. Per your discovery above, the empty_values check should be different for forms.JSONField.

Comment: This nearly worked for me with `django-mysql`. I just had to add `empty_values = [None, "", [], ()]` to the `MyJSONField` defined in fields.py _as well as_ the one defined in forms.py. (When I'd only modified the one in forms.py, entering '{}' gave me a 'This field cannot be blank.' error, instead of a 'This field is required' error.)

Comment: this was raised as a bug with a PR in [2016](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26391) but was closed due to missing tests

Comment: It is discussed in [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27697) - there is a patch but it needs improvement

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue. How did I fix it? In order to bypass the validation process that excludes `{}` as valid json, I added both `blank=True` and `null=True`. For example: `models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True, default=dict)`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your requirements, consider to use blank and/or null.

`media_data=JSONField(blank=True, null=True)`

Comment: yeah but i don't want blank, i want by default an empty dict/ JSON object, which is fundamentally different from a blank or null value.

Comment: @w-- The blank=True , relates to the validation, not to blank values. So it will tell validation to allow the EMPTY_VALUES when validating (say a full_clean). see here for the explanation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#blank . Combine this with a default=dict in the model definition (or default=list) or default=None, as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

This caused problems for me recently, though with `django-mysql` rather than postgres and in a custom `ModelForm` rather than the admin interface.

I ended up overriding my model's `save()` method:

```py
from django_mysql.models import JSONField

class yourModel(model):
    media_data=JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.media_data is None:
            self.media_data = "{}"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in django 4.1 admin screen:

```
class YourModel(Model):
    your_field = JSONField(default=list, null=False, blank=True)
```

I can leave the text field as `[]` and the admin screen saves it fine.

Comment: What happens if you leave the field completely empty (no `[]`) and save? Doesn't it fail saying you're trying to write a null value to a non-nullable column?

Comment: I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

i have similar problem previously. adding `required=False` in your form field will solve the problem.

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    media_data = SimpleArrayField(JSONField(), required=False, widget=forms.Textarea, delimiter='|')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and similarly I created a new Field based class but instead of using a form and model field I just made one that tweaked the innards of the formfield after it gets instantiated.

```
class CustomJSONField(JSONField):
empty_values = [None, '', [], ()]

def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    result = super().formfield(**kwargs)
    result.empty_values = self.empty_values
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to implement a non-nullable (`null=False`) `JSONField` that can be blank (`blank=True`) in the Admin and gets an empty non-null value by default (`default=[]`, `default={}`, etc.), regardless of which database is used.

**blank_json_field.py**:

```
from django.db.models import JSONField as ModelJSONField
from django.forms import JSONField as FormsJSONField

class BlankFormsJSONField(FormsJSONField):
    empty_values = [None, "", (), "null"]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.default = kwargs.pop("default")
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in self.empty_values:
            return self.default
        return super().to_python(value)


class BlankJSONField(ModelJSONField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["blank"] = True
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["default"] = self.default
        kwargs["form_class"] = BlankFormsJSONField
        return super().formfield(**kwargs)
```

**your_model.py**

```
from django.db.models import Model

from blank_json_field import BlankJSONField

class YourModel(Model):
    your_field = BlankJSONField(default=[])
```

This way the value fallbacks to the default one even when Admin users try to save nullable values (like `"null"`).

Developers can specify which non-null yet blank values are reset to the default one. In the provided example, `""` and `"null"` would be reset because they are specified as `empty_values`, whereas `{}` would be saved as is. (Note that using `default=list` instead of `default=[]` won't work with this approach.)