# Django model validation on blank values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

If you define a field with `blank=True` then validation properly allows blank values and if `blank=False` then blank values raise a validation exception.  Usually it's pretty simple, but with `JSONField` it's possible to have one of 3 different blank values which are: `''`, `[]`, `{}`.  Essentially, I'd like to only allow `{}` as the only acceptable blank value.  However, blank values are never passed to custom field validators so it seems like it's not possible through standard means.

```py
def validate_dict(value):
    if not isinstance(value, dict):
        raise ValidationError(
            '"%(value)s" is not valid JSON',
            params={'value': value},
        )

class MyModel(models.Model):
    json = JSONField(default=dict, blank=True, validators=[validate_dict])
```

In the above example, all the "blank" values are immediately seen as valid and `validate_dict` is never called.  If I change `blank=True` to `blank=False` then all blank values are immediately seen as invalid and again `validate_dict` is never called.

I'd like to validate that the stored data is always a `dict`, but it seems to be impossible to validate that the empty value is a `dict` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/56271722/918558 which shows that I can get around the issue by doing the following:

```py
def validate_dict(value):
    if not isinstance(value, dict):
        raise ValidationError(
            '"%(value)s" is not valid JSON',
            params={'value': value},
        )


class DictJSONField(JSONField):
    empty_values = [{}]
    default_validators = [validate_dict]


class MyModel(models.Model):
    json = DictJSONField(default=dict, blank=True)
```

It's always seems to be that you find the answer immediately after crafting the question in SO.  (though I haven't tested it yet)